# Strange output on master side of a pty

Tags: c, linux, pty, job-control

I'm working on a remote shell program and I have a pty created with `forkpty()`. Writing from the follower-end to the leader-end works as expected, but I get strange output on the leader side when I start trying to read on the follower end.

I get this:

```
$
socket->pty: interesting
pty->socket: ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒ɖ^BE<^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^X▒߰^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@▒^E^@^@▒     ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒^@^@▒   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒▒^@^@^@^@^@▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒԰^@^@=L@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
start_shell - DEBUG
========================================
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@job stdin: 0
job stdout: 1
job stderr: 2
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
socket->pty: whoa
pty->socket: @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
start_job - DEBUG
========================================
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@pid: 39665
group_id: 39665^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@39665 (started): cat hello.txt
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
socket->pty: that's weird
pty->socket: @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$^C^@^@▒^E^@^@▒ ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒▒^@^@^@^@^@▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒԰^@^@=L@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

I thought it might have something to do with the debug output, so I disabled it, but:

```
pty->socket: s^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A▒x▒^@^@@`P▒^@^@^A▒▒▒▒▒▒▒^H▒x▒^@^@▒▒x▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒     ^_▒^AM<^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^X"W▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@▒^E^@^@▒        ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒▒^@^@^@^@^@▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒C▒^@^@▒L@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
socket->pty: ?
pty->socket: s^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A▒x▒^@^@@`P▒^@^@^A▒▒▒▒▒▒▒^H▒x▒^@^@▒▒x▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒     ^_▒^AM<^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^X"W▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@▒^E^@^@▒      ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒▒^@^@^@^@^@▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒C▒^@^@▒L@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
socket->pty: what
pty->socket: s^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A▒x▒^@^@@`P▒^@^@^A▒▒▒▒▒▒▒^H▒x▒^@^@▒▒x▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒     ^_▒^AM<^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^X"W▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@▒^E^@^@▒      ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@▒   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒▒^@^@^@^@^@▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒▒C▒^@^@▒L@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

It looks like it's repeating, but I can't figure out what it is.

**Follower's code**

```
fprintf(stdout, "$");
fgets(input_buff, buff_len, stdin);
```

**Leader's code**

```
chars_read = read(leader_fd, &buff, buff_len - 1);
if (chars_read > 0) {
    buff[chars_read] = '\0';
    printf("pty->socket: %s\n", buff);
    write(socketfd, buff, chars_read);
}

chars_read = read(socketfd, &buff, buff_len - 1);
if (chars_read > 0) {
    buff[chars_read] = '\0';
    printf("socket->pty: %s\n" buff);
    write(leader_fd, buff, chars_read);
}
```

When I remove the `fgets` from the follower end my output becomes:

```
socket->pty: what
pty->socket: .txt: No such file or directory
$56152 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56153 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56154 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56155 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56156 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56157 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56158 (st
socket->pty: why?
pty->socket: arted): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56159 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56160 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56161 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56162 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56163 (started): cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
$56164 (started): cat hello.txt
```

Why on earth would a read on the follower side garble the read on the leader side?

Comment: What *exactly* is being sent ant received? Is it some raw binary non-text data? Do you have a [mcve] to show us? What own debugging efforts have you made?

Comment: You're missing a comma after `"` before `buff`